# If five letters from the word SPECIAL are arranged randomly with no repetitions, determine the probability that the word SPICE will be chosen.

Tags: probability, combinatorics, permutations, combinations

Given the word SPECIAL, determine the probability that the word SPICE will be chosen if the letters from "SPECIAL" are arranged randomly without repetitions.

Thanks, in advance.

Comment: Question 1: How many ways are there to choose 5 letters from 7 letters?

Question 2: How many words (not necessarily english words) can be made from each choice of 5 letters?

Comment: Do you know what a "permutation" is?

Comment: Yes... that's precisely what you need to answer the question.

Answer (score 3):

It's $$\frac{1}{7}\cdot\frac{1}{6}\cdot\frac{1}{5}\cdot\frac{1}{4}\cdot\frac{1}{3}$$for each time you have to choose a letter from SPECIAL to write SPICE you have $$\frac{1}{letters/left}$$ possibilities.

Answer (score 0):

It is: $\dfrac{1}{P(7,5)}= \dfrac{1}{\dfrac{7!}{(7-5)!}}= \dfrac{2}{7!}$

Comment: Why do we say 1/P(7,5)? I tried to do it earlier... I actually drew an imaginary tree diagram, and the probability came out as (1/7)(1/6)(1/5)(1/4)(1/3)... but I just want to understand your way now... it's better

Comment: Its the same and my answer used the classical method of finding probability $P(A) = \dfrac{\text{# of ways the event A occurs}}{\text{total number of possible outcomes}}$

Comment: I am satisfied ! Thank you. Would you recommend any book to study and master the basics of the "counting principle" probability problems ?

Comment: There are two dozens of them out there nowadays. My favorite is the book by Ivan Niven's classical The number of choice ( ? ) by the MAA or a more sophisticated one by Stirzaker: Intro to Probability.

Comment: Ivan Niven's book is called [Mathematics of Choice or  How to Count without Counting](https://www.amazon.com/Mathematics-Choice-New-Mathematical-Library/dp/0883856158/ref=cm_cr_arp_d_product_top?ie=UTF8).